# HTML / CSS inline textarea set width to same as input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible by CSS alone, but I'm attempting to create an inline textarea element where the text is selectable but still looks like part of a sentence. It looks fine when the number of characters are known (cols="11") by:

```
<p>To run nload for your device run <textarea readonly cols="11">nload p3p1</textarea> in your terminal.</p>
```

and the CSS:

```
textarea {
    display: inline;
    border:none;
    resize: none;
}
```

Is there a way of doing this dynamically, without specifying the columns for each textarea in CSS? So each textarea is inline and looks unobtrusively part of a normal paragraph but selectable? Failing a CSS solution, is there a (pure) JavaScript one?

Comment: How about using a `<span>` with the "contentEditable" attribute?

Comment: Ah no, the thing I'm trying to avoid is when the website user double or triple clicks the command (for eg.) then it doesn't select the whole paragraph, just the contents of the box..

Comment: Well I don't think that's possible with a `<textarea>` but maybe somebody knows a trick.

Comment: Why dont you try textbox instead of textarea?

Comment: That would be fine also, but how would I set the width of that to the total character width?

Comment: Is this something too far off?

<div>To run nload for your device run <div style="display: inline-block">nload p3p1</div> in your terminal.</div>

Comment: @kallehj Oh goodness, that's precisely what I'm after - man did I overcomplicate that! Never even guessed that would work, now it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to render the input text and calculate the width of the input submitted text based on that render.

A possible sollution is to copy the text into a hidden span and check it's width as illustrated:

```
jQuery('input').on('input', function()
{
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    // Create a widthSpan if we haven't already.
    document.$widthSpan = document.$widthSpan || jQuery('<span style="display: none" />').appendTo(document.body);

    document.$widthSpan.text($this.val());
    $this.css('width', document.$widthSpan.width() + 5);
}).trigger('input');
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/687uew37/.

Do note this is an example which updates as soon as the input's content is changed. Depending on the implementation and usage if this you might need to implement changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to dynamically set the width of your textarea depending on the number of characters inside your textarea.

**HTML:**

```
<p>To run load for your device run <textarea class="tx" readonly>nload p3p1</textarea> in your terminal.</p>

<p>Here is another example which follows the same pattern <textarea class="tx" readonly>your textarea query you can add lots of text. </textarea>You can add a lot of other stuff after it and it will still look like part of your text.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p{
line-height:1.5em;
font-size:14px;
}

textarea {
    margin-bottom:-0.3em;
    border:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:14px;
    display:inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').each(function(){
        //Width of a character:
        var chars = 8;
        //Find out how many characters are in the text area:
        var txLength = $(this).val().length;
        //Calculate the width:
        var txWidth = chars * txLength;
        //Set the width:
        $(this).css({'width':txWidth,'resize':'none'});
    });
});
```

You start by taking each textarea one at the time. The idea is that you already have a font-family predefined and you know the average width of the characters in your font-family. You can find your font-family average character width online or you can estimate if you don't know it (I took a guess here).

In this case the variable `chars` holds the average width value of the character. You then compute the desired textarea width by multiplying the number of characters with the average character width and insert that in your CSS using jQuery's `.css()` function.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ys2Lfrt8/5/

Drawbacks: Not responsive but can be fixed using `@media-queries`